# Error of rasa and rasa X intallation and running the local server

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa, rasa-core, rasa-x

I have installed rasa on Max OSX and this output on the terminal:

```
python3.8 -m pip install rasa
Collecting rasa
  Using cached rasa-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (688 kB)
Processing /Users/zahraa-maher/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/2d/6d/bb/486f8c893f1dcc917860a5b3e2f2ca286c398f7d548ffc649c/aiohttp-3.6.3-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
Collecting apscheduler<3.7,>=3.6
  Using cached APScheduler-3.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting ujson<4.0,>=1.35
  Using cached ujson-3.2.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_14_x86_64.whl (45 kB)
Collecting absl-py<0.11,>=0.9
  Using cached absl_py-0.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (127 kB)
Collecting jsonschema<3.3,>=3.2
  Using cached jsonschema-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56 kB)
Collecting tqdm<4.51,>=4.31
  Using cached tqdm-4.50.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (70 kB)
Processing /Users/zahraa-maher/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/e3/20/a2/d1e894c0ef62547559ba0cca55e27dc5dcf65ad87abea69d32/sanic_jwt-1.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting multidict<5.0,>=4.6
  Using cached multidict-4.7.6-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_14_x86_64.whl (48 kB)
Collecting rasa-sdk<3.0.0,>=2.2.0
  Using cached rasa_sdk-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting redis<4.0,>=3.4
  Using cached redis-3.5.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (72 kB)
Collecting questionary<1.6.0,>=1.5.1
  Using cached questionary-1.5.2-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting async_generator<1.11,>=1.10
  Using cached async_generator-1.10-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
 Processing /Users/zahraa-maher/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/96/aa/c2/aab14cd3ad606228f7c3d151a0ec7da79978964a2b2e92db91/regex-2020.9.27-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
Collecting sentry-sdk<0.20.0,>=0.17.0
  Using cached sentry_sdk-0.19.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (128 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=41.0.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from rasa) (50.3.2)
Collecting jsonpickle<1.5,>=1.3
  Using cached jsonpickle-1.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Collecting packaging<21.0,>=20.0
  Using cached packaging-20.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting fbmessenger<6.1.0,>=6.0.0
  Using cached fbmessenger-6.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting attrs<20.3,>=19.3
  Using cached attrs-20.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
Collecting rocketchat_API<1.10.0,>=0.6.31
  Using cached rocketchat_API-1.9.1-py3-none-any.whl (9.8 kB)
Collecting coloredlogs<15,>=10
  Using cached coloredlogs-14.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (44 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil<2.9,>=2.8
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
Collecting networkx<2.6,>=2.4
  Using cached networkx-2.5-py3-none-any.whl (1.6 MB)
Collecting tensorflow-probability<0.12,>=0.11
  Using cached tensorflow_probability-0.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.3 MB)
Collecting pykwalify<1.8.0,>=1.7.0
  Using cached pykwalify-1.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
Processing /Users/zahraa-maher/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/08/8f/5f/253d0105a55bd84ee61ef0d37dbf70421e61e0cd70cef7c5e1/terminaltables-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz<2021.0,>=2019.1
  Using cached pytz-2020.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (509 kB)
Collecting colorhash<1.1.0,>=1.0.2
  Using cached colorhash-1.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (4.0 kB)
Collecting joblib<0.16.0,>=0.15.1
  Using cached joblib-0.15.1-py3-none-any.whl (298 kB)
Collecting kafka-python<3.0,>=1.4
  Using cached kafka_python-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (246 kB)
Processing /Users/zahraa-maher/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/cd/d4/31/74e1cb4f74bd72a0e74d6fbb28f5093b9a2168df275aa59440/twilio-6.45.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Processing /Users/zahraa-maher/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/bf/4f/4e/831c191578fd8b676533e1bf85e4710e3215c72c1d3d0d6710/colorclass-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting PyJWT<1.8,>=1.7
  Using cached PyJWT-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting pydot<1.5,>=1.4
  Using cached pydot-1.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Processing /Users/zahraa-maher/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/1a/d3/89/63aef88b581e7acc2c48812e6160a2bae57b6ef180f6e1f293/mattermostwrapper-2.2-py3-none-any.whl
Processing /Users/zahraa-maher/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/64/0e/23/0691479628b75b644d805dec9434665a3066e9be25c05cc3b9/pyTelegramBotAPI-3.7.4-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting python-engineio<3.14,>=3.11
  Using cached python_engineio-3.13.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (50 kB)
Collecting cloudpickle<1.5,>=1.2
  Using cached cloudpickle-1.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting python-socketio<4.7,>=4.4
  Using cached python_socketio-4.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (51 kB)
Collecting psycopg2-binary<2.9.0,>=2.8.2
  Using cached psycopg2_binary-2.8.6-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (1.5 MB)
Collecting sklearn-crfsuite<0.4,>=0.3
  Using cached sklearn_crfsuite-0.3.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-estimator<2.4,>=2.3
  Using cached tensorflow_estimator-2.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (459 kB)
Collecting scikit-learn<0.24,>=0.22
  Using cached scikit_learn-0.23.2-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (7.2 MB)
Collecting matplotlib<3.4,>=3.1
  Using cached matplotlib-3.3.3-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (8.5 MB)
Collecting tensorflow_hub<0.10,>=0.9
  Using cached tensorflow_hub-0.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (103 kB)
Collecting scipy<2.0.0,>=1.4.1
  Using cached scipy-1.5.4-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (29.0 MB)
Collecting aio-pika<7.0.0,>=6.7.1
  Using cached aio_pika-6.7.1-py3-none-any.whl (41 kB)
Collecting boto3<2.0,>=1.12
  Using cached boto3-1.16.41-py2.py3-none-any.whl (130 kB)
Collecting tensorflow<2.4,>=2.3
  Using cached tensorflow-2.3.1-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_14_x86_64.whl (165.2 MB)
Collecting webexteamssdk<1.7.0,>=1.1.1
  Using cached webexteamssdk-1.6-py3-none-any.whl (113 kB)
Collecting oauth2client==4.1.3
  Using cached oauth2client-4.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
Collecting pymongo[srv,tls]<3.11,>=3.8
  Using cached pymongo-3.10.1-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (351 kB)
Collecting slackclient<3.0.0,>=2.0.0
  Using cached slackclient-2.9.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Collecting sanic<21.0.0,>=19.12.2
  Using cached sanic-20.9.1-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-text<2.4,>=2.3; sys_platform != "win32"
  Using cached tensorflow_text-2.3.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (2.2 MB)
Collecting SQLAlchemy<1.4.0,>=1.3.3
  Using cached SQLAlchemy-1.3.22-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_14_x86_64.whl (1.2 MB)
Collecting ruamel.yaml<0.17.0,>=0.16.5
  Using cached ruamel.yaml-0.16.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (111 kB)
Collecting numpy<2.0,>=1.16
  Using cached numpy-1.19.4-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (15.3 MB)
Collecting sanic-cors<0.11.0,>=0.10.0b1
  Using cached Sanic_Cors-0.10.0.post3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-addons<=0.12,>=0.10
  Using cached tensorflow_addons-0.11.2-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_13_x86_64.whl (613 kB)
Collecting requests<3.0,>=2.23
  Using cached requests-2.25.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting prompt-toolkit<3.0,>=2.0
  Using cached prompt_toolkit-2.0.10-py3-none-any.whl (340 kB)
Collecting chardet<4.0,>=2.0
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0
  Using cached async_timeout-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Collecting yarl<1.6.0,>=1.0
  Using cached yarl-1.5.1-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_14_x86_64.whl (128 kB)
Collecting tzlocal>=1.2
  Using cached tzlocal-2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting six>=1.4.0
  Using cached six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Processing /Users/zahraa-maher/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/3d/22/08/7042eb6309c650c7b53615d5df5cc61f1ea9680e7edd3a08d2/pyrsistent-0.17.3-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
Collecting certifi
  Using cached certifi-2020.12.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
Collecting urllib3>=1.10.0
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (136 kB)
Collecting pyparsing>=2.0.2
  Using cached pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting humanfriendly>=7.1
  Using cached humanfriendly-9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (86 kB)
Collecting decorator>=4.3.0
  Using cached decorator-4.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.2 kB)
Collecting gast>=0.3.2
  Using cached gast-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (9.8 kB)
Collecting dm-tree
  Using cached dm_tree-0.1.5-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_14_x86_64.whl (95 kB)
Processing /Users/zahraa-maher/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/56/ea/58/ead137b087d9e326852a851351d1debf4ada529b6ac0ec4e8c/docopt-0.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Processing /Users/zahraa-maher/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/13/90/db/290ab3a34f2ef0b5a0f89235dc2d40fea83e77de84ed2dc05c/PyYAML-5.3.1-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
Collecting python-crfsuite>=0.8.3
  Using cached python_crfsuite-0.9.7-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_13_x86_64.whl (186 kB)
Collecting tabulate
  Using cached tabulate-0.8.7-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting threadpoolctl>=2.0.0
  Using cached threadpoolctl-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1
  Using cached kiwisolver-1.3.1-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (61 kB)
Collecting pillow>=6.2.0
  Using cached Pillow-8.0.1-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (2.2 MB)
Collecting cycler>=0.10
  Using cached cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.5 kB)
Collecting protobuf>=3.8.0
  Using cached protobuf-3.14.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (1.0 MB)
Collecting aiormq<4,>=3.2.3
  Using cached aiormq-3.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
Collecting s3transfer<0.4.0,>=0.3.0
  Using cached s3transfer-0.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (69 kB)
Collecting jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1
  Using cached jmespath-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting botocore<1.20.0,>=1.19.41
  Using cached botocore-1.19.41-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.1 MB)
Collecting grpcio>=1.8.6
  Using cached grpcio-1.34.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (3.6 MB)
Collecting google-pasta>=0.1.8
  Using cached google_pasta-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
Collecting astunparse==1.6.3
  Using cached astunparse-1.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from tensorflow<2.4,>=2.3->rasa) (0.35.1)
Collecting h5py<2.11.0,>=2.10.0
  Using cached h5py-2.10.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (3.0 MB)
Processing /Users/zahraa-maher/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/a0/16/9c/5473df82468f958445479c59e784896fa24f4a5fc024b0f501/termcolor-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting opt-einsum>=2.3.2
  Using cached opt_einsum-3.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
Collecting tensorboard<3,>=2.3.0
  Using cached tensorboard-2.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (10.6 MB)
Collecting keras-preprocessing<1.2,>=1.1.1
  Using cached Keras_Preprocessing-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Processing /Users/zahraa-maher/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/5f/fd/9e/b6cf5890494cb8ef0b5eaff72e5d55a70fb56316007d6dfe73/wrapt-1.12.1-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
Collecting requests-toolbelt
  Using cached requests_toolbelt-0.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (54 kB)
Processing /Users/zahraa-maher/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/8e/70/28/3d6ccd6e315f65f245da085482a2e1c7d14b90b30f239e2cf4/future-0.18.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting rsa>=3.1.4
  Using cached rsa-4.6-py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
Collecting pyasn1>=0.1.7
  Using cached pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.0.5
  Using cached pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
Collecting httplib2>=0.9.1
  Using cached httplib2-0.18.1-py3-none-any.whl (95 kB)
Collecting dnspython<2.0.0,>=1.16.0; extra == "srv"
  Using cached dnspython-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (188 kB)
Collecting httptools>=0.0.10
  Using cached httptools-0.1.1-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_13_x86_64.whl (102 kB)
Collecting uvloop>=0.5.3; sys_platform != "win32" and implementation_name == "cpython"
  Using cached uvloop-0.14.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_11_x86_64.whl (1.5 MB)
Collecting httpx==0.15.4
  Using cached httpx-0.15.4-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
Collecting websockets<9.0,>=8.1
  Using cached websockets-8.1-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (64 kB)
Collecting aiofiles>=0.3.0
  Using cached aiofiles-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting ruamel.yaml.clib>=0.1.2; platform_python_implementation == "CPython" and python_version < "3.9"
  Using cached ruamel.yaml.clib-0.2.2-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (149 kB)
Collecting sanic-plugins-framework>=0.9.0
  Using cached Sanic_Plugins_Framework-0.9.4.post1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting typeguard>=2.7
  Using cached typeguard-2.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting idna<3,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting wcwidth
  Using cached wcwidth-0.2.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (30 kB)
Collecting pamqp==2.3.0
  Using cached pamqp-2.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
Collecting tensorboard-plugin-wit>=1.6.0
  Using cached tensorboard_plugin_wit-1.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (779 kB)
Collecting werkzeug>=0.11.15
  Using cached Werkzeug-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (298 kB)
Collecting google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1
  Using cached google_auth_oauthlib-0.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting markdown>=2.6.8
  Using cached Markdown-3.3.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Collecting google-auth<2,>=1.6.3
  Using cached google_auth-1.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (114 kB)
Collecting httpcore==0.11.*
  Using cached httpcore-0.11.1-py3-none-any.whl (52 kB)
Collecting rfc3986[idna2008]<2,>=1.3
  Using cached rfc3986-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
Collecting sniffio
  Using cached sniffio-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0
  Using cached requests_oauthlib-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0
  Using cached cachetools-4.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting h11<0.10,>=0.8
  Using cached h11-0.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
Collecting oauthlib>=3.0.0
  Using cached oauthlib-3.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (147 kB)
Installing collected packages: chardet, async-timeout, attrs, idna, multidict, yarl, aiohttp, pytz, tzlocal, six, apscheduler, ujson, absl-py, pyrsistent, jsonschema, tqdm, PyJWT, sanic-jwt, certifi, urllib3, requests, httptools, uvloop, sniffio, h11, httpcore, rfc3986, httpx, websockets, aiofiles, sanic, sanic-plugins-framework, sanic-cors, humanfriendly, coloredlogs, rasa-sdk, redis, wcwidth, prompt-toolkit, questionary, async-generator, regex, sentry-sdk, jsonpickle, pyparsing, packaging, fbmessenger, rocketchat-API, python-dateutil, decorator, networkx, gast, dm-tree, numpy, cloudpickle, tensorflow-probability, docopt, PyYAML, pykwalify, terminaltables, colorhash, joblib, kafka-python, twilio, colorclass, pydot, mattermostwrapper, pyTelegramBotAPI, python-engineio, python-socketio, psycopg2-binary, python-crfsuite, tabulate, sklearn-crfsuite, tensorflow-estimator, threadpoolctl, scipy, scikit-learn, kiwisolver, pillow, cycler, matplotlib, protobuf, tensorflow-hub, pamqp, aiormq, aio-pika, jmespath, botocore, s3transfer, boto3, grpcio, google-pasta, astunparse, h5py, termcolor, opt-einsum, tensorboard-plugin-wit, werkzeug, pyasn1, pyasn1-modules, cachetools, rsa, google-auth, oauthlib, requests-oauthlib, google-auth-oauthlib, markdown, tensorboard, keras-preprocessing, wrapt, tensorflow, requests-toolbelt, future, webexteamssdk, httplib2, oauth2client, dnspython, pymongo, slackclient, tensorflow-text, SQLAlchemy, ruamel.yaml.clib, ruamel.yaml, typeguard, tensorflow-addons, rasa
ERROR: After October 2020 you may experience errors when installing or updating packages. This is because pip will change the way that it resolves dependency conflicts.

We recommend you use --use-feature=2020-resolver to test your packages with the new resolver before it becomes the default.

sanic 20.9.1 requires multidict==5.0.0, but you'll have multidict 4.7.6 which is incompatible.
tensorflow 2.3.1 requires gast==0.3.3, but you'll have gast 0.4.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow 2.3.1 requires numpy<1.19.0,>=1.16.0, but you'll have numpy 1.19.4 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed PyJWT-1.7.1 PyYAML-5.3.1 SQLAlchemy-1.3.22 absl-py-0.10.0 aio-pika-6.7.1 aiofiles-0.6.0 aiohttp-3.6.3 aiormq-3.3.1 apscheduler-3.6.3 astunparse-1.6.3 async-generator-1.10 async-timeout-3.0.1 attrs-20.2.0 boto3-1.16.41 botocore-1.19.41 cachetools-4.2.0 certifi-2020.12.5 chardet-3.0.4 cloudpickle-1.4.1 colorclass-2.2.0 coloredlogs-14.3 colorhash-1.0.3 cycler-0.10.0 decorator-4.4.2 dm-tree-0.1.5 dnspython-1.16.0 docopt-0.6.2 fbmessenger-6.0.0 future-0.18.2 gast-0.4.0 google-auth-1.24.0 google-auth-oauthlib-0.4.2 google-pasta-0.2.0 grpcio-1.34.0 h11-0.9.0 h5py-2.10.0 httpcore-0.11.1 httplib2-0.18.1 httptools-0.1.1 httpx-0.15.4 humanfriendly-9.1 idna-2.10 jmespath-0.10.0 joblib-0.15.1 jsonpickle-1.4.2 jsonschema-3.2.0 kafka-python-2.0.2 keras-preprocessing-1.1.2 kiwisolver-1.3.1 markdown-3.3.3 matplotlib-3.3.3 mattermostwrapper-2.2 multidict-4.7.6 networkx-2.5 numpy-1.19.4 oauth2client-4.1.3 oauthlib-3.1.0 opt-einsum-3.3.0 packaging-20.8 pamqp-2.3.0 pillow-8.0.1 prompt-toolkit-2.0.10 protobuf-3.14.0 psycopg2-binary-2.8.6 pyTelegramBotAPI-3.7.4 pyasn1-0.4.8 pyasn1-modules-0.2.8 pydot-1.4.1 pykwalify-1.7.0 pymongo-3.10.1 pyparsing-2.4.7 pyrsistent-0.17.3 python-crfsuite-0.9.7 python-dateutil-2.8.1 python-engineio-3.13.2 python-socketio-4.6.1 pytz-2020.4 questionary-1.5.2 rasa-2.2.2 rasa-sdk-2.2.0 redis-3.5.3 regex-2020.9.27 requests-2.25.1 requests-oauthlib-1.3.0 requests-toolbelt-0.9.1 rfc3986-1.4.0 rocketchat-API-1.9.1 rsa-4.6 ruamel.yaml-0.16.12 ruamel.yaml.clib-0.2.2 s3transfer-0.3.3 sanic-20.9.1 sanic-cors-0.10.0.post3 sanic-jwt-1.4.1 sanic-plugins-framework-0.9.4.post1 scikit-learn-0.23.2 scipy-1.5.4 sentry-sdk-0.19.5 six-1.15.0 sklearn-crfsuite-0.3.6 slackclient-2.9.3 sniffio-1.2.0 tabulate-0.8.7 tensorboard-2.4.0 tensorboard-plugin-wit-1.7.0 tensorflow-2.3.1 tensorflow-addons-0.11.2 tensorflow-estimator-2.3.0 tensorflow-hub-0.9.0 tensorflow-probability-0.11.1 tensorflow-text-2.3.0 termcolor-1.1.0 terminaltables-3.1.0 threadpoolctl-2.1.0 tqdm-4.50.2 twilio-6.45.4 typeguard-2.10.0 tzlocal-2.1 ujson-3.2.0 urllib3-1.26.2 uvloop-0.14.0 wcwidth-0.2.5 webexteamssdk-1.6 websockets-8.1 werkzeug-1.0.1 wrapt-1.12.1 yarl-1.5.1
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.4; however, version 20.3.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/zahraa-maher/rasa-init-demo/venv/bin/python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

you can see that It has this with the output:

```
ERROR: After October 2020 you may experience errors when installing or updating packages. This is because pip will change the way that it resolves dependency conflicts.

We recommend you use --use-feature=2020-resolver to test your packages with the new resolver before it becomes the default.

sanic 20.9.1 requires multidict==5.0.0, but you'll have multidict 4.7.6 which is incompatible.
tensorflow 2.3.1 requires gast==0.3.3, but you'll have gast 0.4.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow 2.3.1 requires numpy<1.19.0,>=1.16.0, but you'll have numpy 1.19.4 which is incompatible.
```

what is this mean and how I can solve it? what I should type?

and then I have installed rasa x on the terminal also to start the local server,

and those errors have appeared for me:

```
ERROR: After October 2020 you may experience errors when installing or updating packages. This is because pip will change the way that it resolves dependency conflicts.

We recommend you use --use-feature=2020-resolver to test your packages with the new resolver before it becomes the default.

sanic 20.9.1 requires multidict==5.0.0, but you'll have multidict 4.7.6 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed GitPython-3.1.11 Mako-1.1.3 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 alembic-1.4.3 attrs-19.3.0 cffi-1.14.4 cryptography-2.9.2 gitdb-4.0.5 isodate-0.6.0 kafka-python-1.4.7 pika-1.1.0 pycparser-2.20 python-editor-1.0.4 rasa-x-0.34.0 smmap-3.0.4 ujson-1.35
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.4; however, version 20.3.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/zahraa-maher/rasa-init-demo/venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

and the local server is not running when I type http://localhost:5002/ on my browser

how I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could you share the commands that you use to install rasa and rasa-x? We recommend installing rasa and rasa-x in a python virtual environment. Step-by-step guide see [installation guide](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/installation/).

```
ERROR: After October 2020 you may experience errors when installing or updating packages. This is because pip will change the way that it resolves dependency conflicts.

We recommend you use --use-feature=2020-resolver to test your packages with the new resolver before it becomes the default.

sanic 20.9.1 requires multidict==5.0.0, but you'll have multidict 4.7.6 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed GitPython-3.1.11 Mako-1.1.3 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 alembic-1.4.3 attrs-19.3.0 cffi-1.14.4 cryptography-2.9.2 gitdb-4.0.5 isodate-0.6.0 kafka-python-1.4.7 pika-1.1.0 pycparser-2.20 python-editor-1.0.4 rasa-x-0.34.0 smmap-3.0.4 ujson-1.35
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.4; however, version 20.3.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Users/zahraa-maher/rasa-init-demo/venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

This error message is more likely a python library compatibility problem.
Your `multidict`, `gast`, `numpy` packages are not the version that rasa needs. A solution for this is to use virtual environment and install the compatible version of `multidict`, `gast`, `numpy` packages in that virtual environment.

Comment: Thank you very much, You mean a virtual environment such as PyCharm?

Comment: Not exactly. Short answer: PyCharm is an integrated development environment (IDE), while virtual environment is a tool to isolate dependencies for your project.